# why does debug show two records, when console only shows (correctly) one in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

This is a very confusing situation, I am wondering if it is because I am in the "new" controller.

I a new Email record with the following view:

```
<% title "New Email" %>

<div id = "form">
  <%= render :partial => 'form' %>
</div>

<div id = "tabs">
  <h2>Campaign Activity</h2>
  <%= debug @campaign %> 

</div>
```

Emails are created nested in a Campaign Id.

From console, campaign.emails shows just 1 email, which is correct.

But, the debug @campaign line above displays 2 email records, the second looks like the following:

```
- &id001 !ruby/object:Email 
  attributes: 
    created_at: 
    title: 
    campaign_id: 1
    updated_at: 
    days: 
    subject: 
    message: 
  attributes_cache: {}

  changed_attributes: 
    campaign_id: 
  errors: !ruby/object:ActiveRecord::Errors 
    base: *id001
    errors: !map:ActiveSupport::OrderedHash {}
```

I am in the new view, which has a standard new controller:

```
  def new
    @campaign = Campaign.find(params[:campaign_id])
    @email = @campaign.emails.build
  end
```

**QUESTION:  From the view, how can I correctly grab the associated emails for the campaign and why am I seeing a "phantom" record?**

Comment: Yes, it's because you're calling @campaign.emails.build - that is your "phantom" record. To more easily / efficiently iterate over them, assign the emails to an instance variable in the controller before you call build. i.e. @emails = @campaign.emails then in the view loop over @emails.

Comment: I see...I should have added that in the view I apply a @campaign.emails.sort so it errors out over the phantom emails when doing an a <=> b comparison

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to make sure i understood correctly: your `@campaign` has one email record, in your new-action you execute `@campaign.emails.build`, which adds a new (empty) email and you want to be able to iterate over all emails except the newly created one?

To iterate over all emails and not show the 'new' one, do something like

```
<div id = "tabs">
  <h2>Campaign Activity</h2>
  <% @campaign.emails.reject {|x| x.new_record?}.sort{|x,y| x <=> y}.each do |email| %>
      ... show the data of the email here ...
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Comment: Well...let's see, I think it errors out because I have a .sort method applied on @campaign.emails....